# Override get value function from a custom FormControl

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm trying to create a custom form control on angular2 and I facing an issue when I try to get the value of all the form

```
this.form_c.value
```

I want to override the get value of my custom form control

I try to find if I can do something like, but no success

```
private _val:any;
@Input set value(x:any) {
...this._val = x;
}

get value {
return this._val + "My mod";
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use Angular's Reactive Forms with Form Builder?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Angular Reactive forms. in the component I'm using a directive as well

Comment: I use these things daily. I mock you up something real quick.

Comment: Why not just use `ngModel` and have the event bindings?

Comment: I have several components and the easy way to use the API is getting the values as a group. Even I never imagine that was so difficult to try to override the get. :(

Comment: I know this is really old now but did you ever figure out a way to do this? I'm wanting to do the same type of thing with a date range control

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case to solve where a custom form group should return null in certain cases. I'm not sure if it perfectly matches your case, but maybe it will help someone with similar use cases. I guess it would be possible to bend this functionality to what you're trying to achieve.

Note that the project in question is on @angular/forms 11.2.9, so i can't guarantee this works in newer versions. Fiddling around with internal functions is usually a bad idea, but that was the only way i was able to achieve what i needed.

The solution is *very* hacky. so i'd rather find a way around it...

```js
class NullableFormGroup extends FormGroup {
    private isNull = false;

    public patchValue(value, options?) {
        this.isNull = value === null;

        if(value !== null) {
            super().patchValue(value, options);
        }

        this.updateControls();
        this.updateValueAndValidity(options);
    }

    protected _updateValue() {
        // HACK: override internal _updateValue function.
        // this allows this form group to have the value null.
        const _this = this as any;
        _this.value = this.isNull ? null : _this._reduceValue();
    }

    protected _allControlsDisabled() {
        // HACK: override internal _allControlsDisabled function.
        // this prevents the null value not being returned
        // to a parent object when all controls are disabled

        if (this.isNull) {
            return false;
        }

        // original content of this function. calling super is not possible here,
        // as super can't be cast and the function is internal.
        for (const key of Object.keys(this.controls)) {
            if (this.controls[key].enabled) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return Object.keys(this.controls).length > 0 || this.disabled;
    }

    private updateControls() {
        // enable/disable controls. This prevents validation in case of isNull.
        for (const key in this.controls) {
            if (this.isNull) {
                this.controls[key].disable();
            } else {
                this.controls[key].enable();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example of how to make a custom form using Reactive Forms in Angular:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: null,
      lastName: null
    });
  }
```

How to get and set values from form elements:

```
this.myForm.get('firstName').value;
this.myForm.get('lastName').setValue('Smith');
```

Import Validators to set requirements on specific form elements:

```
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';

this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: [null, Validators.required],
    lastName: [null, Validators.maxLength(16)]
})
```

Using your form in HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" />
</form>
```

[More Info](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) on Reactive Forms.

Comment: Already know that, thanks anyway, the thing is in your AppComponent if we are able to override the get value function, ex if in the text you wrote Jhon Smith, we create an override of get value to add or modify that value when you trigger this.myForm.value 

{  firstName : "Jhon Smith ***"  }

Comment: That can happen if we create a directive that we call it on the <input tempDirective ... />

Comment: So you are looking for something to detect when a form element changes? You can subscribe to the form element's valueChanges method and manipulate data accordingly.

Comment: No, something like this

@Output() get value() {
  return this.control.value + "AAA";
 };

Comment: I dont want to call the function in every change of value

Comment: So when and how often should said function happen?

Comment: Just when you retrieve the values, this.myForm.value or this.myForm.controls.firstName.value

Comment: Ok, so say I have a function that I am using that retrieve the form with its values. If I need to send this across components at a specific time, I would probably use an EventEmitter to Emit an event that contains the form object so that I can retrieve the object anywhere I like.

Comment: What do you want? a custom form control like https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html or a custom Form